# Como establecer el valor inicial de un radio button después de la carga

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en JS para generar dinámicamente las preguntas que necesito, al generar las preguntas, la idea es marcar por defecto las que se guardan en la base de datos, y aquí es donde tengo el problema como veo todo es un flujo único y no marca los radio button debido a que no se ha cargado todo, como hago para validar que se hayan cargado las preguntas para ahí si marcar los radio buttons?

Cargo las preguntas dinámicamente

```
function carguepreguntas(data) {
    proceso = data;
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: `../../api/questions/${proceso}`,
        type: 'GET'
    }).done((data, status, xhr) => {
        cantidadpreguntas = data.length;

        $('#preguntas-div').html('');
        data.forEach((question, indx) => {
            $('#preguntas-div').append(`
                    <a for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label" id="${question.id}">${question.pregunta}</a>
                    <label class="checkbox"> 
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question-${question.id}" id="S${question.id_pregunta}" value="1"/></label>
                    <label class="checkbox"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="question-${question.id}" id="N${question.id_pregunta}" value="0"/></label>`
            );
        });

    });
}
```

como quedan cargas en HTML

`````
<div class="row parametrosControlPreguntas" id="preguntas-div">
  <a for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label" id="1">Pregunta1</a>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question-1" id="S1" value="1">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="N1" value="0">
  </label>

  <a for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label" id="2">Pregunta2</a>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question-2" id="S7" value="1">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="N7" value="0">
  </label>

  <a for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label" id="3">Pregunta3</a>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question-3" id="S11" value="1"></label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="question-3" id="N11" value="0">
  </label>

  <a for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label" id="4">Pregunta4</a>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question-4" id="S7" value="1">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="question-4" id="N7" value="0">
  </label>
</div>
````
marco las opciones, para el ejemplo dejo una

````
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#S1').prop('checked', true);
    
});
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

por si a alguien le sucede algo parecido, el problema era que la ejecución de las funciones no se hace de forma secuencial debido al asincronismo de javascript, por lo que a veces cargaba y otras veces no, por lo que opte por trabajar con async y await y con ello logre solucionar el inconveniente.  Muchas gracias, saludos